# Powershell : Get-ACL and get permissions for specific user on a remote folder

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ACL \\machine_name\folder1 | Format-List *
```

Gives me the below including the Access rights for users (in AccessToString)

```
**AccessToString          : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  AppendData
                          NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  -536805376
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                          BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                          BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize**
AuditToString           :
AccessRightType         : System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights
AccessRuleType          : System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule
AuditRuleType           : System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule
AreAccessRulesProtected : True
AreAuditRulesProtected  : False
AreAccessRulesCanonical : True
AreAuditRulesCanonical  : True
```

But below gives me empty :

```
Get-ACL \\machine_name\folder1| Format-List * | select AccessToString
```

ultimately, I want to get the entry for a specific given user in the AccessToString e.g. get only the access rights for  "BUILTIN\Administrators.
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove `| Format-List *`

Comment: Gives only partial data :
--------------
"NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  AppendData..."                                             Also - how do I get rights for a specific user?

Comment: `Get-ACL . |Select -Expand AccessToString`

Comment: Many thanks. That -expand does give the list. How do I search for a specific user in that list to get all the access rights for that user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, one should never pipe the output of any Format-* cmdlets into other cmdlets. Why? Because the output of the Format-* cmdlets are not the objects which you are working with on the pipeline. They are specialized objects for formating information on the screen.

If we take the command `Get-Acl c:\ | Format-List * | Get-Member` we will see that there are five objects of these five .NET Types which are passed from the Format-List cmdlet to the Get-Member cmdlet:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
- Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
- Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
- Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData
- Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData

These objects are there only for Format-List to display nicely. Also Get-Member does not show any of these objects to have any `AccessToString` property.

The `AccessToString` property is just a blob of text representing the ACL. This is not suitable to filter on instead what one should do is to dive into the `Access` property and filter the access control entries (ACEs) on their `IdentityReference` property.

You will have better luck with this:

```
Get-Acl c:\ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | 
  Where-Object identityreference -eq "BUILTIN\Administrators"
```